# eggNOG API, how's it work?

Tags: phylogenetics, bacteria, api, taxonomy, eggnog

**Background** eggNOG uses seed orthologues which correspond to its own internal database, so for example `J421_1876` can be placed in its online search engine [here](http://eggnog5.embl.de/#/app/home). This will recover the function and species classification. Brief output

> Carbohydrate transport and metabolism gluconolactonase activity

.. and lots of associated species. Thats useful information but not very amenable to coded solutions.

**Aim** I want to replicate this via its API, i.e. to be placed in a pipeline.

Thus eggNOG API is [here](http://eggnog5.embl.de/#/app/api) - but I can't figure out, here's the instructions

> [http://eggnogapi5.embl.de/nog_data/[dataformat]/[attributes]/[nogname]](http://eggnogapi5.embl.de/nog_data/%5Bdataformat%5D/%5Battributes%5D/%5Bnogname%5D)

**Question** Does anyone know how to use the API to interrogate using the `seed orthologue` code?

There are alternatives which involve LOADS of hard drive space (not very attractive).